# Simulating input in Windows logon screen, using a driver

Tags: c#, windows-7, keyboard, driver, simulate

I'm writing an open-source remote desktop tool, similar to VNC and TeamViewer. I've noticed that TeamViewer continues capturing the screen at the Switch Users or Workstation Locked screen - and allows the remote user to type in the password and unlock the workstation. I want to do the same.

I've read:

[Updated: Interacting with the user on the windows logon screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317880/updated-interacting-with-the-user-on-the-windows-logon-screen)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9485530/capturing-image-during-windows-logon-invalid-password

[Adding command button to Windows Logon screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186900/adding-command-button-to-windows-logon-screen)

[hook a hotkey from windows logon screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583326/hook-a-hotkey-from-windows-logon-screen)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183241/launch-windows-on-screen-keyboard-at-logon-screen-on-win7

[Driver to Simulate Keypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979544/driver-to-simulate-keypress)

[Removing Windows Logon screen through a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011047/removing-windows-logon-screen-through-a-service)

[How to catch a key in Windows 7 logon screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098156/how-to-catch-a-key-in-windows-7-logon-screen)

[Displaying Window on Logon Screen Using C# in Windows XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103427/displaying-window-on-logon-screen-using-c-sharp-in-windows-xp)

From these posts, I've gathered that simulating input in an isolated session definitely isn't a simple call to SendInput(). But is it possible using a driver (I believe it's specifically a keyboard filter driver, but I'm not sure)? If so, I'm thinking of writing, in C#, a service (so that it runs outside the user's session) that interacts with the Interception driver to simulate key presses.

In response to: "why don't you just try it?", there isn't a .NET wrapper for Interception yet for me to test such a service, and so if the general consensus concludes that this isn't possible, I don't want to spend the time writing that .NET wrapper.

I found [an keyboard driver called Interception (that will be released open-source in the future)](http://oblita.com/Interception.html). You can directly [find the source here (the source is only the C communication API wrapper surrounding the actual kernel driver)](https://github.com/oblitum/Interception/blob/master/windows/interception.c).

Another question I have...I'm confused about what files make up a driver. His Interception DLL library programmed in C compiles to a .DLL. But aren't drivers of some .sys extension - how would you compile that Interception DLL into an actual driver - and then how would you install it?

**EDIT:** [A .NET wrapper does exist](https://github.com/candera/kchordr). I modded the sample console app to type my entire password when I pressed the 'x' key, and it worked successfully - not only at the workstation locked screen, but also at the Windows logon screen. So it works.

**Edit:** [C# wrapper library for this keyboard driver is here](https://github.com/jasonpang/Interceptor).

Comment: I'm in the same situation. Did you actually try 'SendInput' from a windows service to see if any input is being sent to the logon screen - while it's active?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, the actual drivers are not open source. The driver installer installs them (keyboard.sys and mouse.sys), what's open source is only the API of communication with them.
I'm planning a rewriting of the kernel components before open sourcing it too.

Comment: Edited my post, and how exciting - an open-source keyboard and mouse driver. Thanks so much.

Comment: So did the opensourcing go well? It seems only the API is still open source, but no word about the DLL/SYS

Answer (score 1):

For other people interested in the answer: yes, it works.

Use the .NET wrapper for the Interception keyboard driver found at https://github.com/candera/kchordr, and play around. It will replace keys even at the Windows logon screen.