# Trap keyboard input from windows logon screen

Tags: java, windows, security, authentication, keyboard-input

I want to do following things to be done my Java project:-

1. Lock Windows desktop.
2. Detect key press event when windows desktop is locked.
3. Save entered keys from keyboard in a text file.

First step is done using this code:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation");
```

Comment: Java is the wrong language for this, though I'm not sure it should be done at all.

Comment: Why do you want to log key presses when passwords are entered?

Comment: Mh, locking a workstation is exactly that: Locking a workstation. Just as trapping Ctrl-Alt-Del is a "protected" keystroke that you cannot easily trap, the logon screen is totally separated from the user's desktop screen. In Windows API, there is the concept of a "WinStation". What runs on the user´s "WinStation" is totally isolated from what runs when the logon screen is shown. Which mean you won´t easily write an app that executes on the user´s desktop and monitors the keystrokes that are typed when the logon screen is active. At least not using official (documented) Windows APIs.

Comment: You could write a system-wide keyboard monitor, but you will have a hard time getting that one certificated/signed as "compatible"/"trusted".

Comment: Though i just want to turn on webcam when a key is pressed

Answer (score 1):

User Applications will never be able to do this due to security concerns. However, you can get around the restriction if you use a driver to intercept input at a lower level. [This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652358/simulating-input-in-windows-logon-screen-using-a-driver) discusses a similar problem. [The linked driver](http://oblita.com/Interception.html) looks like a good fit for your purpose.